# Create XSD from a refracted cs class from an exe

Tags: c#, .net

I have a cs class which is refracted from an exe using a tool. Now I want to create respective XSD of that class. Can anybody help me out please. Thanks in advance.

I have tried to do this by using xsd.exe but it doesnt work as expected
xsd /c /l:CS -t:pathtodll

Comment: Did you try `xsd.exe`? In fact, this will work on `.exe` or `.dll` alone, no need to extract anything - just use `xsd.exe path\to\your.exe`

Comment: I tried it but gives error while processing some other class. So I need a way to generate XSD from this CS file

Comment: you may want to tell others about the exact error on `xsd.exe` and about other steps you've already tried - apparently the question gets downvoted because it lacks such details.

Comment: I tried this `xsd pathtodll` but gave this error:
Error: There was an error processing 'abc.dll'.
  - There was an error reflecting type 'abc.someclass'.
  - Cannot serialize member 'System.ComponentModel.Component.Site' of type 'System.ComponentModel.ISite', see inner exception for more details.
  - Cannot serialize member System.ComponentModel.Component.Site of type System.
ComponentModel.ISite because it is an interface.

Answer (score 2):

Ok after so many do this and do that... what I did is Created a new ClassLibrary project with that particular class. Then built it and created the XSD by using 
`xsd.exe pathToThisProjectsDll`